# local repo has lost its connection to remote

Tags: git, github

A couple of months ago I set up a new local repo linked to a remote on github.  I've been happily committing changes to my local and pushing them up to my origin without a problem until last week.
Suddenly when I tried to do a push to the remote I got

```
$ git push origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Stopping and restarting Bash seemed to fix the problem.  But yesterday I tried to push and got the same error.  Only this time stop/starting Bash didn't help.

My local repo appears fine.  I can examine the log and see all my commits.
The remote on github also appears ok.
I would like to find the ssh connection string on github and reset my gitconfig.  But I cannot find it. I remember copy pasting it when I created the repo.  But I can no longer locate it.

So in addition to asking for help to be able to push, I would also ask if anyone has seen this problem and what migh have caused it?

Comment: are you sure you aren't meaning to do something like: `git push origin master` or `git push origin dev_somedesc`.

Comment: what does 'git remote -v' say?

Comment: Yes, the command I use to push up is 'git push origin master' 
'git remote -v' produces no output at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check what 'git remote -v' says.

[image]

To see the github ssh link, login and click on Clone or Download.

[image]

Finally, use 'git remote set-url origin ...' to make the change per https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/. Perhaps you changed the repo owner? Strange about the BASH though.

Comment: I applied the following:
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git

and received the following response:
fatal: No such remote 'origin'

And still    git remote -v    produces no output.

Comment: I used, instead:
git remote add origin git@github.com:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git
git remote -v now produces the expected result.

Yet when I run git push origin master, I still get the same response:
fatal: No such remote 'origin'

Comment: Sometimes if you're connecting to your own git, VPN issues also may cause this. Disconnect and reconnect and do 'git pull' to check.